# React Navigation bottom tab navigator not rendering new tabs in Expo Snack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I started with the minimal example of tab-based navigation found at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation, and I was trying to add additional tabs. I duplicated one of the functions associated with the two existing tabs in the example and renamed it appropriately, and then I added a Tab.Screen within the Tab.Navigator in the export default function. The new tab will appear with the name I gave it, however the text within the function does not show when I click on the new tab. It is clearly changing because the other text disappears and the screen is just blank except for the tab bar.

I tried deleting one of the default tabs but no dice. Does anyone know what could be causing this (or more accurately, what I'm doing wrong)? The unedited version can be found at the link above and my code is below. Thank you for your help.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function TestScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Test!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Test" components={TestScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: The third screen you used prop components={TestScreen} it should be only component.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Oh man it's been a while now. I think the comment above yours from Abhishek helped, but I can't remember if it fixed the problem (couldn't mark it as an answer but I did give it an upvote so it helped in some way). I will say I have abandoned Expo Snack because I was having issues with its behavior as my app became more intricate. It was as if the app was getting cached so changes I made weren't registering properly. But not sure if this problem was related to that or a separate issue. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It is best practice to move the functions rendering the different component screens into their own files. File structure could look like features/screens/component. There is a typo in your code on Tab.Screen for test screen, it should be "component={TestScreen}" remove the s from component.